# Numerical solution of the Richards' equation

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, finite-element-method, finite-difference-method

I am trying to solve Richards' equation to model fluid flow in soil. The governing partial differential equation, initial condition, and boundary conditions are:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The analytical solution of the problem is:

[image]

[image]

C in the analytical solution is a typo (i.e., C=c). The last equation is used for the transformation of both the analytical and numerical solutions.

I have tried both FEM and FDM solvers within the context of NDSolve. However, both methods lead to an error in the numerical solution as shown in the figure below:

[image]

The code used to obtain the analytical and numerical solutions is as follows:

```
\[Alpha] = 3/10;
hd = -20;
L = 50;
ks = 1/10;
\[Theta]s = 45/100;
\[Theta]r = 15/100;
\[CurlyEpsilon] = Exp[\[Alpha]*hd];
c = \[Alpha]*(\[Theta]s - \[Theta]r)/ks;
pde = c*D[k[t, z], 
      t] - (D[k[t, z], {z, 2}] + \[Alpha]*D[k[t, z], z]) == 0;
bc1 = k[t, 0] == 0;
bc2 = k[t, L] == If[t > 0, 1 - \[CurlyEpsilon], 0];
ic = k[0, z] == 0;
solalt = NDSolveValue[{pde, bc1, bc2, ic}, k, {t, 0, 5}, {z, 0, L}, 
  Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
      "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
        "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.001}, 
        "IntegrationOrder" -> 4}}}]
sum[t_, z_] := 
 Sum[(-1)^k*(Pi*k/L)*Sin[(Pi*k/L)*z]*
   Exp[-((1/c)*((\[Alpha]^2/4) + (Pi*k/L)^2))*
      t]/((1/c)*((\[Alpha]^2/4) + (Pi*k/L)^2)), {k, 1, 300}]
hbar[t_, z_] := (1 - \[CurlyEpsilon])*
  Exp[\[Alpha]*(L - z)/
     2]*((Sinh[\[Alpha]*z/2]/Sinh[\[Alpha]*L/2]) + (2/(L*c))*sum[t, z])
h[t_, z_] := (1/\[Alpha])*Log[\[CurlyEpsilon] + hbar[t, z]]
hanalytical = Table[h[1, z], {z, 0, L, 1}];
knumerical = Table[solalt[1, z], {z, 0, L, 1}];
hnumerical = 
  Table[(1/\[Alpha])*Log[knumerical[[i]] + \[CurlyEpsilon]], {i, 1, 
    Length[knumerical]}];
zdata = Table[z, {z, 0, L, 1}];
hnumericald = 
  Table[{zdata[[i]], hnumerical[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[zdata]}];
hanalyticald = 
  Table[{zdata[[i]], hanalytical[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[zdata]}];
ListPlot[{hanalyticald, hnumericald}, 
 AxesStyle -> {{Thick, 17}, {Thick, 17}}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["z(m)", 17], Style["h(m)", 17]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 52}, {-25, 1}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, -25}, 
 Mesh -> None, 
 PlotMarkers -> {{\[FilledCircle], 10}, {\[FilledCircle], 10}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, Red}, LabelStyle -> Black, 
 TicksStyle -> Black, 
 Joined -> {True, True, True, False, True, False}, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[PointLegend[{Style["h-Analytical", 13], 
     Style["h-Numerical", 13]}, LegendMarkerSize -> 16, 
    LegendFunction -> "Frame"], {0.14, 0.78}], ImageSize -> 500]
```

I could not find the reason why the numerical solution did not match the analytical one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The analytical solution with which you are trying to compare the numerical solution does not converge to the initial data. See this test

```
Table[hanalytical = Table[h[t, z], {z, 0, L, 1}];
 knumerical = Table[solalt[t, z], {z, 0, L, 1}];
 hnumerical = 
  Table[(1/\[Alpha])*Log[knumerical[[i]] + \[CurlyEpsilon]], {i, 1, 
    Length[knumerical]}];
 zdata = Table[z, {z, 0, L, 1}];
 hnumericald = 
  Table[{zdata[[i]], hnumerical[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[zdata]}];
 hanalyticald = 
  Table[{zdata[[i]], hanalytical[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[zdata]}];
 ListPlot[{hanalyticald, hnumericald}, 
  AxesStyle -> {{Thick, 17}, {Thick, 17}}, 
  AxesLabel -> {Style["z(m)", 17], Style["h(m)", 17]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 52}, {-25, 1}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, -25}, 
  Mesh -> None, 
  PlotMarkers -> {{\[FilledCircle], 10}, {\[FilledCircle], 10}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Black, Red}, LabelStyle -> Black, TicksStyle -> Black,
   Joined -> {True, True, True, False, True, False}, 
  Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic}, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[PointLegend[{Style["h-Analytical", 13], 
      Style["h-Numerical", 13]}, LegendMarkerSize -> 16, 
     LegendFunction -> "Frame"], {0.14, 0.78}], ImageSize -> 500, 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"t = ", t}]], {t, 0, 1, .2}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

It can be assumed that when `t` equals zero, the series converges very slowly. In other words, 300 terms of the series are insufficient to describe the functions at the initial moment of time. On the other hand, this means that for very large values of t the numerical analytical solution must converge. Indeed, as time increases, the convergence of the numerical and analytical solution gets better and better.
[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Thank you for your answer Alex. Increasing the number of terms of the infinite series tends to improve the convergence behavior of the analytical solution for small t. However, it does not have an impact on the discrepancy of analytical and numerical solutions at t=5. The problem is solved with a meshless method in https://doi.org/10.1016/j.camwa.2018.01.022 which shows perfect agreement between analytical and numerical results.

Comment: @Tayfun I will check this paper and give you an answer. However, the analytical solution itself seems to need improvement.